# console PHP produces opcode output

Tags: linux, php, console

I have PHP running on WSL on windows along with nginx+php-fpm.
The web component is running php OK, but console PHP produces opcode output for some reason.
For example i have such PHP file:

> ?php
>     echo "test OK\r\n";

When i run it as

> php test.php

It will produce this output:

> root@computer:/mnt/d/php/zona.sp# php test.php
>
> $_main: ; (lines=2, args=0, vars=0, tmps=0)
>       ; (after pass 1)
>       ; /mnt/d/php/zona.space/test.php:1-3
>   L0 (2):     ECHO string("test ok
>   ")
>   L1 (3):     RETURN int(1)
>
> $_main: ; (lines=2, args=0, vars=0, tmps=0)
>       ; (after pass 2)
>       ; /mnt/d/php/zona.space/test.php:1-3
>   L0 (2):     ECHO string("test ok
>   ")
>   L1 (3):     RETURN int(1)
>
> $_main: ; (lines=2, args=0, vars=0, tmps=0, no_loops)
>       ; (after pass 7)
>       ; /mnt/d/php/zona.space/test.php:1-3
>       ; return  [long] RANGE[1..1]
>   L0 (2):     ECHO string("test ok
>   ")
>   L1 (3):     RETURN int(1)
>   test ok

Why this happens?

> root@computer:/mnt/d/php/zona.sp# php -v
>
> PHP 7.2.9-1 (cli) (built: Aug 19 2018 06:56:13) ( NTS )
>
> Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
>
> Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>
> with Zend OPcache v7.2.9-1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your PHP configuration, you have set [`opcache.opt_debug_level`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.opt_debug_level) to a nonzero value. Remove this setting from your `php.ini` or the included ini file where it is set, or set it back to its default value of 0.

Comment: Thank you! Did not mention this when install opcache.